# How to force UIView to accept only last touch event

Tags: ipad, uipopovercontroller

I've created one customView,in which, on click event it shows imagepicker selection option.I've added 5 instances on customView in other View say 'myView'.

Now in 'myView' if user selects all 5 views at same time.Then 'myView'shows 5 imagePicker selection option.How to force 'myView' to recognize last touch.so that it should show only one imagePicker selection or it should dismiss  other popover when user selects Gallery/Camera.

.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create a UIPopoverController instance in your customView

like this...
.h file:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPopoverController *popover;
```

Then, when you need the popover to show up, instaniate it like this (.m file):

```
self.popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:someViewController];
```

Now there will always be just only one Popover shown

Comment: Thanks.i couldn't find a way around so i removed imagepicker selection option from customView and added a delegate method on tap so when user taps image then in 'myView' delegate method it shows KxMenu.So at a time only one KxMenu is shown.It solved my problem.